# Google Maps API v.3: Use default marker icon if not found at url

Tags: google-maps, icons, google-maps-markers

Currently google maps api doesn't show any icon if marker's icon attribute is set to a url that returns with 404. How can I tell google maps to use the default brick colored marker icon if user supplied icon url is broken? I can't find a way to determine if the icon is actually found or returns with 404.

Example:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: googlemap,
    title: "Click here!",
    icon: SOME_URL_THAT_FAILS (or not)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the following way to solve my own case. In case someone needs this:

```
var icon = {
    url: SOME_URL_THAT_FAILS (or not)
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: googlemap,
    title: "Some Title"
});

var i = new Image();
i.src = SOME_URL_THAT_FAILS (or not);

i.onload = function () {
    marker.setIcon(icon); //If icon found go ahead and show it
}
i.onerror = function () {
    marker.setIcon(null); //This displays brick colored standard marker icon in case image is not found.
}
```